# Returning results from stored procedure as IEnumerable

Tags: c#, sql, ienumerable

i am not sure how to properly complete this - i have a stored proc and i want to return the results as an IEnumberable

```
  public IEnumerable GetGuids(int id)
    {
        SqlCommand _command = new SqlCommand("storedProc");
        _command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        _command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ItemID", id);

        return _command.ExecuteReader();
    }
```

when i run this i get: `ExecuteReader: Connection property has not been initialized.`

Comment: Your `SqlCommand` needs a `SqlConnection`.  Check the second parameter of the constructor.

Comment: You should read some tutorial on how to use SqlCommand. I don't think you really want to return _command.ExecuteReader() - http://csharp-station.com/Tutorial/AdoDotNet/Lesson03

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pass the connection object like this `GetGuids(int id, SqlConnection conn)`

```
 SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand ("query", conn);
```

Answer (score 4):

Your SqlCommand does not have a corresponding connection. Either use:

```
_command.Connection = conn;
```

or create the SqlCommand by using `conn.CreateCommand(...)`

Answer (score 1):

Initialize the SqlCommand with the SqlConnection and be sure that the SqlConnection is open.
After that ExecuteReader gives an SqlDataReader and you must read through the reader and read the values

```
SqlDataReader reader = _command.ExecuteReader();

while(reader.Read()
{
   // readvalue of reader["columname"] and insert into a list or yield return it.
}
```